# Ionic push notification when app is open

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, push

When app is open I receive a push notification.

I use
pushObject.on('notification')

But I imidiately receive this notification and don't see it after in notifications bar.

Is it possible to keep notification and do nothing when app is open. In other words keep the same behaviour when app is closed

Answer (score 0):

`forceShow: true` will solve this problem. worked in ionic 1

```
android: {
     senderID: SENDER_ID,
     icon: "icon",
     forceShow: true 
},
```